# Laravel Define Session for Logged in Users

Tags: php, laravel, auth0

I'm using Google auth0 to authorize users on my server and after that I wanted to put the token in cookies in the user's browser. I achieve that but there's a problem I with initating the session. How can I just make a simple session for a client in Laravel? In PHP it's something like:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['userid'] = $userID;
```

After successful authorization by Google, the server redirects to
client-side with cookies:

```
return redirect($url)
    ->withCookie(cookie()->forever('token', $access_token))
    ->withCookie(cookie()->forever('name', $name));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like so:

```
return response($content)
    ->header('Content-Type', $type)
    ->cookie('token', $access_token)
```

Or, you can use a session:

```
// Via a request instance
$request->session()->put('access_token');

// Get session value
$token = $request->session()->get('access_token');
```